# Excel VBA - other sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a Excel VBA that gets 100 lines per time in a table and send them to a new excel file separately, but I don't know how. Is there a way?

There are 2000 lines in the table, so I want 20 separate files.

Comment: What part of your current code isn't working?

Comment: I don't know how to make the while() (if it's needed) to select 100 lines at time and pass to another file, it's at 0%

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post any code you have and let us know what you've attempted.

Comment: You could use a `While` loop to go through the table until you get to the end (or, if you know there are exactly 2000 lines, a `For i = 1 to 2000 Step 100` loop), with (possibly) a `For j = i To i+99` loop within that to process each "block".  Hopefully that will get you to at least 10%.  If you can't then get to 100%, post the code you are using and tell us what you are stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has some special cell types, one of which returns the cell showing the maximum extent of data in the worksheet. Research xlCellTypeLastCell in the help file. The returned value does not mean there is data in that particular cell, but that there is no data in rows or columns past that row and column ref.

Eg You can select the last cell in a worksheet with the line below.

```
ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
```

Then use the row number of that cell to set the bounds for your loop.